# Pytesseract OCR

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

This is my first time coding.
I would kindly like guidance on how to extract text from Image Passport/ID.
Using python-Tesseract OCR, I have done my research on the documentation on Tesseract but I am not getting enough explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this is not the place to look for general guidance; please ask specific questions about code

Answer (score 0):

Import PIL and pytesseract

```py
import PIL.Image
import pytesseract
```

Load your image

```py
my_image = PIL.Image.open("Path/To/My_Image.jpg")
```

Run tesseract on it

```py
my_image_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(my_image)
print(my_image_text)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I am getting an error.                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/PythonProject1/PythonEye/Image.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PIL.Image
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 94, in <module>
from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)             and I don't understand why i keep on getting this error.

Comment: I have googled your error message, and it seems to usually be a conflict when installing PIL and Pillow, as installation problems mainly depend on your system, I invite you to search it (and in this case the problem seems well documented).